# How to tell which FTP directory I am in?

Tags: ftp, sftp

I received FTP credentials from my client to start developing a website I am working on for them, but I'm not sure what directory they gave me access to.

It just shows "/" on the top of `Transmit` for Mac OS X Yosemite. I only have TLS access, no SFTP/SSH.

It's definitely not the main directory because the main site is still running and all I see is the `ftp_quota` file.

I don't really want to bother the client if I don't absolutely have to.

Answer (score 3):

Most ftp (and sftp) clients have a `pwd` command which you can run.  However, if your connection shows "/", that would be the same result as the `pwd` command.

You are *probably* connected to a server running in a chroot, which uses as its "/" some other directory, and the ftp server cannot tell you what that is.

Further reading:

- [32.3. Setup a chroot user environment](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap29sec296.html) (RedHat Edition -A Hands on Guide)
- [VSFTP chroot or jail users – limit users to only their home directory howto](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vsftp-chroot-users-limit-to-only-their-home-directory.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your account is chrooted. That means it's explicitly configured not to allow you to see the physical path where the account home directory is located.

For details, see for example [Wikipedia chroot article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot):

> A chroot on Unix operating systems is an operation that changes the apparent root directory for the current running process and its children. A program that is run in such a modified environment cannot name (and therefore normally cannot access) files outside the designated directory tree.

So you cannot find out yourself.